# How much can we electrically charge an object?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electrons, conductors

I am aware of this [SE Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100627/what-determines-how-much-electrical-charge-an-object-can-hold), however, I am doubtful about the answer. Assume that we have a solid conductive sphere of a finite size located far from us in space. If we decide to bombard the sphere with high-energy electrons, how many surplus electrons can the sphere contain? Is it correct that classical electromagnetics predicts an infinite amount of superfluous electric charges on the sphere? I want to know, for a negatively charged sphere, what force causes the electrons not to be thrown away from the sphere due to the great repulsion between the electrons.

Comment: A stable solid without constraints has generally a number of positive charges equal to the number of negative charges, if another negative charge is added the solid becomes unstable and will reach the equilibrium by getting rid of a negative charge.

Comment: @M06-2x - most elements have a bound state single negative ion. Only a few, particularly the noble gases, will autoionize back to a neutral atom.

Answer (score 1):

Classically, you can charge forever.

QED says differently. For spheres smaller than the Compton wavelength of the electron, eg, nuclei, when the charge reaches $Z\alpha \approx 1$, sparking off the vacuum occurs. That is, it becomes energetically favorable to screen the charge by producing an electron positron pair.

So the electron the screens the nuclei to $Z-1$, and the positron is ejected.

You can work out the equivalent for a macroscopic sphere.